# How to perform MANOVA test in R?

Tags: r, statistics, manova

I am trying to find any interaction between independent variables in `Group` and 2 samples of dependent variables `Level1` and `Level2` in my `data` dataset (size reduced).

```
Group Level1 Level2
a     1      0
a     2      3
a     4      3
b     2      4
b     1      3
b     3      2
c     2      4
c     3      2
c     1      3
```

For this, I want to run a manova test.
However when I am trying to run `manova(data[,2:3] ~ as.factor(Group), data=data)`, I get `invalid type (list) for variable 'data[,2:3]'` error although `data[,2:3]` IS a list.

(Obviously this is my first time trying to use `manova` and basically `R`  for this task and I have very basic knowledge of `R` so maybe I am completely wrong in what I am doing in general).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run it like this using `cbind`:

Data

```
df <- read.table(header=T, text='Group Level1 Level2
a     1      0
a     2      3
a     4      3
b     2      4
b     1      3
b     3      2
c     2      4
c     3      2
c     1      3')
```

Solution:

```
> manova( cbind(Level1,Level2) ~ Group, data=df)
Call:
   manova(cbind(Level1, Level2) ~ Group, data = df)

Terms:
                   Group Residuals
resp 1          0.222222  8.666667
resp 2                 2        10
Deg. of Freedom        2         6

Residual standard errors: 1.20185 1.290994
Estimated effects may be unbalanced
```